# Move Visual Studio(MSDN) subscriptions into specific management group

Tags: azure, powershell

We currently have a lot of subscriptions in Azure which we managed, these range from the different execution environments(dev,test,etc) and are all grouped inside a management group structure to make RBAC and policies easier.  The problem we are facing at the moment is that out root of the management group structure has a bunch of Visual Studio Professional(/MSDN) subscriptions.  We are looking to automate a script to check for the offerId of the subscription and move all these into a specific management group.

So far we have had no joy or functions using the Powershell or Azure CLI to actually filter the subscriptions by OfferId. Even if I could get a subscription export with OfferId I could use that list to automate move all these subscriptions into a specific management group. Has anybody experienced the same, or should I rather just leave those subscriptions lying there. The idea behind having it separate is to have it isolated and more control over it, reporting on costs etc for the management group will also be an advantage.

Comment: Is that you want to migrate your subscriptions to Azure management group?

Comment: Yes, but I need a way to IDENTIFY all the Visual Studio Professional subscriptions and get them in a usable list. The only way to truely identify these subscriptions is by using the OfferId.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move subscriptions to the Azure management group with PowerShell, please refer to the following script :

```
#create management group
New-AzManagementGroup -GroupName 'Contoso'

#move Subscription
New-AzManagementGroupSubscription -GroupName 'Contoso' -SubscriptionId ''
```

Besides, **please note that if you want to do that, you need to have enough RBAC permissions**
[image]

For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/manage#move-subscriptions-in-the-hierarchy.

Comment: Thank Jim, my problem here is how to IDENTIFY a subscription and get it in a usable list by OfferId.

Comment: According to my research, we cannot have any way to get the Azure Subscription ID by offer ID. Because Microsoft does not provide any rest pi to get the offer ID. For more details, please refer to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f746be1b-6927-4260-a29a-7339525fb96d/get-offer-id-from-subscription-using-code?forum=windowsazurepurchasing and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list

Comment: @Aklopper Do you have any other concerns?